# Exporting a variable from a Windows batch file to Cygwin

Tags: batch-file, cygwin, environment-variables

I want to initialize my Cygwin environment with a variable coming from a batch file

```
@set myvar=test
%BASH% --login -c "set"
REM hope to see myvar
```

So I want myvar with its value eventually be available in bash.

Comment: The environment is passed to subprocesses so you should see the variable change in bash. Unless bash does very weird things with the environment it gets passed.

Comment: you are right, make it an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the batch file append your variable to your bash.bashrc file to create bash environmental variables, like so:

```
export croot=/cygdrive/c
```

Then you access that croot variable like so

```
export cc=$croot/CC
```

or

```
alias cdcc='cd $croot/CC'
```

The path on my machine is `C:\cygwin\etc\bash.bashrc` ... yours may differ.

Note that the variable won't be available in running cygwin sessions, only new ones.

Comment: Running the batch multiple times then clutters the initialization script for bash, though.